# Two's complement VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am just trying to make a simple two's complement device in VHDL but it is throwing back this really annoying error and I'm unsure what I have done wrong. Probably something very silly...The error is
"Error (10327): VHDL error at twocompliment.vhd(21): can't determine definition of operator ""nand"" -- found 0 possible definitions"

The code is

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity twoscompliment is
      generic
      (
              Nbits : positive := 8 
       );
 port 
( 
           --Inputs
           A : in std_logic_vector (Nbits-1 downto 0);
           --Outputs
           Y : out std_logic_vector (Nbits downto 0)
);
end twoscompliment;

architecture twoscompliment_v1 of twoscompliment is
 begin
  Y <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(A NAND '1') + '1');
 end twoscompliment_v1;
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: I won't change your code, but it is “two's complement”.

Comment: A is a std_logic_vector (an array type) and '1' is an enumeration literal compatible with std_logic (not an array type). 

There is no definition for an operator taking the two types (or closely related types) in either package you are using (std_logic_1164 and numeric_std). 

The common way of two's compliment conversion is taking the inverse (not) of a number and adding one. 

There's a not operator that will do that for std_logic_vector. 

You also need the expression on the right hand side to return a length that matches Y on the left hand side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
architecture twoscompliment_v1 of twoscompliment is
signal temp : std_logic_vector(Nbits-1 downto 0);
begin
  temp <= not A;
  Y    <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(temp + 1));
end twoscompliment_v1;
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a closing paren after the last occurrence of temp.

Comment: And your target length for Y, (9) doesn't match the length of the value on the right hand side, (8).  It's a simulation error.

Comment: Shouldn't this be: `std_logic_vector(unsigned(temp) + 1)`?

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me you are trying to negate the input number...  Maybe I'm missing something vital, but the other answers give a solution which, whilst achieving the goal, appear to be one step more obfuscated than they need to be.

Barring the ugly conversions, what's wrong with

```
y <= std_logic_vector(-signed(resize(unsigned(A)), y'length));
```

Of course, I would argue that if A and Y are supposed to be representing signed numbers (or unsigned numbers), they should be expressed as such:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity twoscomplement is
  generic
  (
     Nbits : positive := 8 
  );
  port 
  ( 
     A : in  unsigned (Nbits-1 downto 0);
     Y : out signed   (Nbits downto 0)
  );
end entity twoscomplement;

architecture a1 of twoscomplement is
begin
  Y <= -signed(resize(A, Y'length));
end architecture;
```

Let's check the results:

```
entity test_twoscomplement is
end entity;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
architecture test of test_twoscomplement is
    signal A : unsigned (7 downto 0);
    signal Y : signed(8 downto 0);
begin
    dut : entity work.twoscomplement port map (A => A, Y=>Y); 

    process
    begin
       for i in 0 to 255 loop
         A <= to_unsigned(i, A'length);
         wait for 1 ns;
         assert to_integer(Y) = -i severity error;
       end loop;
       report "tests done";
       wait;
     end process;
end architecture;
```

Running with GHDL:

```
$ ghdl -a twoscomp.vhd 
$ ghdl --elab-run test_twoscomplement
twoscomp.vhd:40:8:@256ns:(report note): tests done
```

Success!

Comment: You'd notice both your answer and the selected answer have the right hand side and left hand side of the signal assignment operator with different length std_logic_vectors derived from expressions.  Y has a range one greater than A.  They'll analyze but will generate run time errors. `nvc -r test   
** Fatal: length of target 9 does not match length of value 8
 File twos.vhdl, Line 21`

Answer (score 1):

```
architecture twoscompliment_v1 of twoscompliment is
    constant ONE:   UNSIGNED(Y'RANGE) := (0 => '1', others => '0');
begin
     Y <= std_logic_vector(unsigned (not A) + ONE);
end twoscompliment_v1;
```

Comment: The target Y has a length of 9, which is why the constant ONE does as well. The numeric_std package has a "+" operator for unsigned that takes the MAX length of either left or right operand and returns an UNSIGNED of that length.

Answer (score -3):

Hi gentleman basically 2's complement is done by inverting the binary bits of a
given no. i.e changing ones to zeroes and zeroes to ones, after that add the
binary bit '1' to the Least significant bit of the given binary number. Now I
have a program

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity twoscomplementconversion is Port (
    bin : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    twos : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0)
);
end twoscomplementconversion;

architecture Behavioral of twoscomplementconversion is

    component fourbitadder45 Port (
        a : in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        b : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        cin : in  std_logic;
        cout : out  std_logic;
        sum  : out  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
    );
    end component;

    signal onebit : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0001";
    signal cin1   : std_logic:='0';
    signal notbin : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal cout1  : std_logic;

begin

    notbin <= not(bin);

    twos1: fourbitadder45 port map (
        a    => notbin,
        b    => onebit,
        cin  => cin1,
        cout => cout1,
        sum  => twos
    );

end Behavioral;
```

#### The four bit adder program is given below:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity fourbitadder45 is Port (
    a : in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    b : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    cin : in  std_logic;
    cout : out  std_logic;
    sum  : out  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)
);
end fourbitadder45;

architecture Behavioral of fourbitadder45 is
    component fulladder2 Port (
        a : in  std_logic;
        b : in  std_logic;
        cin : in std_logic;
        cout : out std_logic;
        sum : out std_logic
    );
    end component;

    signal c:std_logic_vector (3 downto 1);

begin

    fa1 :fulladder2 port map (a => a(0), b => b(0), cin => cin,  cout => c(1), sum => sum(0)); 
    fa2 :fulladder2 port map (a => a(1), b => b(1), cin => c(1), cout => c(2), sum => sum(1));
    fa3 :fulladder2 port map (a => a(2), b => b(2), cin => c(2), cout => c(3), sum => sum(2)); 
    fa4 :fulladder2 port map (a => a(3), b => b(3), cin => c(3), cout => cout, sum => sum(3)); 

end Behavioral;
```

#### four bit adder contains 4 full adders so the full adder program is given below:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity fulladder2 is Port (
    a : in  std_logic;
    b : in  std_logic;
    cin : in std_logic;
    cout : out std_logic;
    sum : out std_logic
);
end fulladder2;

architecture Behavioral of fulladder2 is
begin
    sum <= a xor b xor cin;
    cout <= ((a and b) or (b and cin) or (cin and a));
end Behavioral;
```

I hope that answers the question. This is a method there are many different methods

Comment: College professors show adders implemented using "AND", "OR", and/or "XOR" only so they can teach math structures.  Industry, OTOH, simply uses "+".  Industry tools understand "+" and readily implement the correct hardware structures.  OTHO, when you implement them using "AND", "OR", ... you take the risk of ending up with poor quality hardware as it may not map as well into the target device as "+" does.