# VHDL typecast signed to std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl

I am looking at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428277/twos-complement-vhdl) and below answer which is a nice solution to produce two's complement:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity twoscomplement is
  generic
  (
     Nbits : positive := 8 
  );
  port 
  ( 
     A : in  unsigned (Nbits-1 downto 0);
     Y : out signed   (Nbits downto 0)
  );
end entity twoscomplement;

architecture a1 of twoscomplement is
begin
  Y <= -signed(resize(A, Y'length));
end architecture;
```

I want to use the said example to have two's complement and then make a "**16-bit subtractor**". The code will look like the following:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity subtractor_16bit is
  Port (    a     : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
            b     : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
            cin   : in STD_LOGIC;
            sum   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
            cout  : out STD_LOGIC;
            over  : out STD_LOGIC
            );
end subtractor_16bit;

architecture Behavioral of subtractor_16bit is

component fulladder_16bit is
  Port (
          a     : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
          b     : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
          cin   : in STD_LOGIC;
          sum   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
          cout  : out STD_LOGIC;
          over  : out STD_LOGIC
         );
end component;

component twoscomplement is
  Port (
        A : in  unsigned (15 downto 0);
        C : out signed (15 downto 0) 
        );
end component;

signal n1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);

begin

    twoscomplement_1: twoscomplement port map (a => a ,c => n1); --ERROR
    fulladder_16bit_1: fulladder_16bit port map (a => a, b => n1, sum => sum , cin => cin, cout => cout, over => over);

end Behavioral;
```

However, I am receiving an error saying: 
***Error: type error near a; current type std_logic_vector; expected type unsigned.***

Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: There are at least three errors visible without a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In  `twoscomplement port map (a => a ,c => n1); --ERROR`. C in twoscomplement is declared as type signed while n1 is defined as type std_logic_vector. the size of A and C have a default generic value that isn't modified here, length 8 and 9 respectively while A is 16 long as is C. The generic needs to be be passed and the length of n1 adjusted. Two's complement can also be preformed in an expression without a structural element.

Comment: Just look at the implementation of `twoscomplement` and you can already see an example of type casting...

Comment: `type_conversion ::= type_mark ( expression )` Explicit *type conversions* are expressions converting between *closely related types*. Two array types are closely related if and only if the types have the same dimensionality and the element types are closely related.  A type is closely related to itself. IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.6 Type conversions.  Array types signed and std_logic_vector are closely related having the same element base type.

Answer (score 1):

As nobody is answering this and nobody is down voting it, I will answer.

Look at the error

> Error: type error near a; current type std_logic_vector; expected type unsigned.

Now look at entity `subtractor_16bit`.

```
[...]
entity subtractor_16bit is
    Port (    a     : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
[...]
    component twoscomplement is
        Port (
            A : in  unsigned (15 downto 0);
[...]
    twoscomplement_1: twoscomplement port map (a => a ,c => n1);
[...]
```

What do you see? **`twoscomplement` expects an `unsigned`, while `a` is `std_logic_vector`!** Just like the error says.

`std_logic_vector` and `unsigned` are two separate types. As VHDL is a strongly typed language, you cannot just put the data from one type to another. You need to use type conversion.

For unrelated types, you should implement a type conversion function. Or functions, if you want bidirectional conversion. E.g.

```
function (input : type_a) return type_b;
```

But in this case, `std_logic_vector` and `unsigned` have the same underlying type, `std_logic`. (`std_ulogic` actually since VHDL-2008 I believe.)
In that case you can convert from one type to another explicitly. E.g.

```
    signal a_u : unsigned(y downto 0);
    signal a_slv : std_logic_vector(y downto 0);
begin
    a_u <= unsigned(a_slv);
```

---

Next, your not instantiating the `twoscomplement` component properly. The entity has a generic `Nbits`. By default you set it to 8. But in your architecture `Behavioral` of `subtractor_16bit`, you feed it with 16 bits, without changing the generic value. That doesn't work.

Also: `twoscomplement` has two ports: `A` and `Y`. But in `subtractor_16bit` you start using `A` and `C`. That's bad coding practice.

---

Finally, you can drop the `component` declarations. Just instantiate the entities from the library. E.g.

```
twoscomplement_1: entity work.twoscomplement [...]
```

---

So, `subtractor_16bit` should look something like this:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity subtractor_16bit is
    Port (
        a     : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        b     : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        cin   : in STD_LOGIC;
        sum   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        cout  : out STD_LOGIC;
        over  : out STD_LOGIC
        );
end entity;

architecture structural of subtractor_16bit is
    use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
    signal n1 : signed(a'range);
begin
    twoscomplement_1: entity work.twoscomplement
        generic map(
            NBits => a'length
            )
        port map (
            a => unsigned(a),
            y => n1
            );
    fulladder_16bit_1: entity work.fulladder_16bit
        port map (
            a => a,
            b => std_logic_vector(n1),
            sum => sum,
            cin => cin,
            cout => cout,
            over => over
            );
end architecture;
```

...

## HOWEVER this will still not work.

As you see on your entity `twoscomplement`, port `A` has a size of `NBits`, and port `Y` has a size of `NBits`**+1**. That is because you seem to want to keep 16-bit value precision. So when converting unsigned to signed, you need to add a 17th bit for the sign. As a result, the rest of you code will need to be modified!

.... But this can be fixed a different way. I will learn you something about two's complement: `-a = not(a) + 1`.

Proof (Take 4 bits signed precision):

- 0 = b'0000 => -0 is `not(b'0000)+1` = `b'1111'+1` = `b'0000'`
- 7 = b'0111 => -7 is `not(b'0111)+1` = `b'1000'+1` = `b'1001'`
- -6 = b'1010' => 6 is `not(b'1010)+1` = `b'0101'+1` = `b'0110'`

See?

So now I will solve your puzzle for you:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity subtractor_16bit is
    Port (
        a     : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        b     : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        sum   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
        cout  : out STD_LOGIC;
        over  : out STD_LOGIC
        );
end entity;

architecture structural of subtractor_16bit is
begin
    fulladder_16bit_1: entity work.fulladder_16bit
        port map (
            a => a,
            b => not(b),
            sum => sum,
            cin => '1',
            cout => cout,
            over => over
            );
end architecture;
```

You will still need to change/fix the `cout` and `over` behavior...